# Zend start basic web site

Tags: php, zend-framework

im newbe to Zend Framework, i wanted to make 1 website using ZF tutorial but can't make it to work, i got error `T_STRING` in `/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php on line 10`.
code in 10 is as follow:

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/zf2 for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2013 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
*/

namespace Zend\Mvc; <-- here is error.

use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\Stdlib\ResponseInterface;
```

i went and started to read how declare `namespace` but it seems all is good.
Can it be because of hosting provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need PHP version >= 5.3 to support namespace.**